# selenium: wrong link clicked when window is small

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing some automated GUI testing with selenium (Python binding + Firefox driver). On this page we're having problem with, there is button that I want to click but it's at the lower part of the page (I'm selecting the button via id). The default size of the Firefox window isn't large enough to show it. So the actual clicked element is one from the tab bar which is always visible.

If I manually resize the window during the test, it runs smoothly.

This looks like a bug to me TBH. I'm wondering if this is a known feature and a work around exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Actions Chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to scroll to the element

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

That will make the button visible and you will be able to click on it. You can also use explicit wait to make sure the button is visible.

Comment: @lang2 didn't scroll? or just still clicking the wrong button?

Comment: didn't scroll. Tried both Firefox and Chrome driver and neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [location_once_scrolled_into_view](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location_once_scrolled_into_view) on the element. It is a property that returns the elements location, but it has the added side-effect of scrolling to the element first if it is not in view already.

`element.location_once_scrolled_into_view`.

Comment: Can you provide the web page? Or is it behind authentication?